# Can't change height and width input type textarea

Tags: php, html, css

I've been struggling a lot with this code, it is a thing I usually find very easy.

```
<?php
echo "<td style=\"width: 25%; text-align: right;\"><label for=\"forum_desc\">Desc</label></td>";
echo "<td style=\"padding: 0 0 0 10px;\"><input type=\"textarea\"  name=\"forum_desc\" size=\"80\" value=\"{$array['desc']}\"></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</tr>";
?>
```

When I change size from "80" to 90 instead, it just gets more width, not height, I've tried adding some other codes to this but I just get 500 HTTP error then, So I am obviously doing something wrong, I want to make the box big as I am trying to make this the "forum description".

It currently looks like this
[image: Image of forum post]

If you get my point, the label "Desc" should have bigger height and width, right now it is just a straight line.

Comment: There is no such thing as `<input type="textarea">` it is <textarea></textarea>`

Comment: Please post the HTML and remove the PHP and jQuery and JavaScript tags. It is unrelated to any of those

Comment: why are you closing `<tr>` twice but not opening it once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `input[type="textarea"]` in the html. You need a textarea element instead:

```
<textarea rows="" cols=""></textarea>
```

At this element you can use it's properties like `rows, cols` to make it taller and wider.

---

As per your comment:

```
echo "<td style='padding: 0 0 0 10px;'>"
echo "<textarea name='forum_desc' rows='80' cols='40' value='{$array['desc']}'>";
echo "</td>";
```

Comment: I'll show you my code https://gyazo.com/412039e8a5961894b690dbf086978021 where am I supposed to put your code? what should I replace and NOT get HTTP 500 Error

Comment: @Omega, rather than echo'ing styles you should do what Jai suggested and within your css use `input[type="textarea"]`

Comment: @OmegaCebbo glad this helped you.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `input[type=textarea]` . Use the `textarea` tag with the rows attribute for height and cols for width instead

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50">
    Use rows for the height
</textarea>
```

And if you use ' for the outerString and " for the inner String you don't have to escape them
e.g.

```
echo "Hello 'Mathias' ";
```

or

```
echo 'Hello "Mathias" ';
```

In your case change the echo with the `type="textarea"`

```
echo "<td style=\"padding: 0 0 0 10px;\"><textarea name=\"forum_desc\" cols=\"80\" rows=\"20\" value=\"{$array['desc']}\"></td>";
```

better

```
echo '<td style="padding: 0 0 0 10px;"><textarea name="forum_desc" cols="80" rows="20" value="{$array['desc']}"></td>';
```

Comment: I'll show you my code https://gyazo.com/412039e8a5961894b690dbf086978021 where am I supposed to put your code? what should I replace and NOT get HTTP 500 Error

Comment: I tried your "better" code, it looks good but it gives me HTTP 500 Error.

Answer (score 0):

This code

`<input type=\"textarea\"`

doesnt exists you should use the HTML like above:

`<textarea rows="20" cols="20"></textarea>`

This code will apply `cols="20"` Five columns as you wanted width and `rows="20"` as height.

Your code should look like this:

`<textarea name=\"forum_desc\" rows=\"20\" cols=\"20\">{$array['desc']}</textarea>`
Hope it helps.

[Font - w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tag_textarea.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to the `textarea` and add css for height

```
<style>
.inc_height {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
}

</style>
```

Then run your code with class

```
<?php 

$array['desc'] = 'desc';

echo "<td style=\"width: 25%; text-align: right;\"><label for=\"forum_desc\">Desc</label></td>";
    echo "<td style=\"padding: 0 0 0 10px;\"><input type=\"textarea\" name=\"forum_desc\" size=\"80\" value=\"{$array['desc']}\" class=\"inc_height\"></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from `<input type="textarea"` does not exists, is this not much simpler?

```
?>
<tr>
  <td style="width: 25%; text-align: right;"><label for="forum_desc">Desc</label></td>
  <td style="padding: 0 0 0 10px;">
    <textarea name="forum_desc" style="height:50px; width:50%">{$array['desc']}</textarea>
  </td>
</tr><?...
```